# Django cannot get dialog box to display relevant information

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two forms that I am using on one (html page below) page. One form (create_task_form) create's tasks, and the other (edit_task_form) should edit/show tasks. To make things more difficult on myself I decided to display the tasks in a list, and when a user clicks on a task, it should display a form with the task details in a dialog box. Again, the create dialog box works as should, however I cannot figure out how to populate the (edit_task_form) edit/show form for a existing task from a list in a dialog box with the relevent task info.

**Views.py: Edited**

```
    def status(request, project_id, task_id=None):
    need_owner_list = Task.objects.filter(project__id=project_id, status=0)
    in_progresss_list = Task.objects.filter(project__id=project_id, status=1)
    pending_review_list = Task.objects.filter(project__id=project_id, status=2)
    t = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id) 
    p = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)


    if project_id:
        p = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    else:
        p = None
  #  if task_id:
  #      t = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
  #  else:
  #      t = None


    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        post_task = PostTaskForm(request.POST)

        if post_task.is_valid():
            task = post_task.save(commit=False)
            task.project = p
            task.save()
            url = reverse('status', args=[project_id])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url) 
    else:
        post_task = PostTaskForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        t = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
        tform = PostTaskForm(request.POST, instance = t)

        if form.is_valid():
            task = tform.save()
            url = reverse('status', args=[project_id])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)    
    else:
        tform = PostTaskForm(instance=t)

    c = Context({
    'need_owner_list': need_owner_list,
    'in_progresss_list': in_progresss_list,
    'pending_review_list': pending_review_list,
    'project': p,
    'request': request,
    'pform': post_task,
    'task_id': task_id,
    'project_id': project_id,
    'task': t,
    'tform': tform,
    })
    return render_to_response('project/status.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**HTML Page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} project status {% endblock %}

{%block content %}
<body>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/status.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/create_task.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/status_box.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/list_items.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/ownerless_task_list.css">

<!-- These are the scripts for the drag and drop functionality. -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascript/jquery.sortable.js"></script>    

</head>

<div id=lists_box>
    {% if need_owner_list %}
        <ul id="needs_owner" class="connected list">
            {% for task in need_owner_list|slice:":20" %}
                <li class="row1"><a href="#divModalDialog1" >{{ task.title }} {% url task task.id%}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <div id="divModalDialog1" class="divModalDialog" type="hidden">
        <div id=task_div>
            <a href="">X</a>

       <form id="edit_task_form" action="{{ task }}" value="{{ task }}" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="{{ task }}"/>

                    {% csrf_token %}
            {{ pform }}

                <input type="SubmitEdit" value="Submit Edit" onclick="self.close()">
            <input type="Reset" value="Reset">
           </form>
       </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <ul id="needs_owner" class="connected list">
        <li class="row1">No tasks are available.</li>
    </ul>    
{% endif %}


{% if in_progresss_list %}
    <ul id="in_progress" class="connected list">
        {% for task in in_progresss_list|slice:":20" %}
            <li class="row1"><a href="{% url edit_task task.pk %}">{{ task.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul id="in_progress" class="connected list">
        <li class="row1">No tasks are available.</li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}


{% if pending_review_list %}
    <ul id="pending_status" class="connected list">
        {% for task in pending_review_list|slice:":20" %}       
            <li class="row1"><a href="{% url task task.pk%}">{{ task.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul id="pending_status" class="connected list">
        <li class="row1">No tasks are available.</li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
</div>

<!-- START:This section below is deals with the submit task popup window -->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <script>
            $(function() {
                  $('.sortable').sortable();
                        $('.handles').sortable({
                            handle: 'span'
                            });
                        $('.connected').sortable({
                            connectWith: '.connected'
                            });
                        $('.exclude').sortable({
                            items: ':not(.disabled)'
                            });
            });
   </script>
<!-- The JS is added here to load after login. If this is added the the top of the page it conflicts with login_link.js -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascript/create_task.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <a id="submit_task">submit task</a>
    <div id="task_popout">
       <a id="task_popoutClose">X</a>

               {% if form.has_errors %}
                    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
               {% endif %}

       <form id="create_task_form" action="" value="submit_task" method="POST">
               <input type="hidden" name="project" value="{{ project_id }}"/>

                {% csrf_token %}
        {{ pform }}

               <input type="Submit" value="Submit Task" onclick="self.close()">
                <input type="Reset" value="Reset">
           </form> 

   </div>
   <div id="taskbackgroundPopup"></div>
{% else %}
    <p id="login_message">Please <a style="color:blue;" href="#authenticate"    id="task_chat">log in</a> to submit/edit tasks or particapate in chats.</p>
{% endif %}

    <div id="ticket_stats">
        <div id="owner_label" class="text">Owner:</div>
        <div id="owner" class="text">{{project.owner|safe}}</div>
        <div id="tags_label" class="text">Tags:</div>
        <div id="tags" class="text">{{project.tags|safe}}</div>
        <div id="created_label" class="text">Created:</div>
        <div id="created_date" class="text">{{project.date_created|date:"d/m/Y"}}</div>
        <div id="updated_label" class="text">Updated:</div>
        <div id="last_updated" class="text">{{project.date_updated|date:"d/m/Y"}}</div>
    </div>


</body>
{%endblock%}
```

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='')
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=50, editable=False)
    owner           = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    problem         = tinymce_models.HTMLField(verbose_name='') 
    date_created    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    date_updated    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    tags            = TagField(verbose_name='')


    def set_tags(self, tags):
        Tag.objects.update_tags(self, tags)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tags

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

#This overrides the save function in the project/views.py module. It checks the
#created date against the updated date, and updates the updated date if needed.
#Also this takes the title and slugifies it so it can be rendered in the URL.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.date_created = datetime.now()
        self.date_updated = datetime.now()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class PostProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'Needs Owner'),
    ('1', 'In Progress'),
    ('2', 'Comp/Pend/Review'),
    ('3', 'Complete')
)

class Task(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project        = models.ForeignKey(Project, editable=False)
    assignee    = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    task_desc   = models.TextField()
    solution    = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='0', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    date_created    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    date_updated    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.date_created = datetime.now()
        self.date_updated = datetime.now()
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.object_pk

class PostTaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

**URLs.py**

```
url(r'^status/(?P<idea_id>\d+)$', 'status', name='status'),
url(r'^status/(?P<idea_id>\d+)/(?P<task_id>\d+)$', 'status', name='status_task'),
```

**TL;DR**

How can I get a the edit_task_form to display the relevant data from Tasks so that a user can edit/view a task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'd make the sample a little shorter so people can parse it better...  maybe I missed something but, where's the javascript that does the dialog box? is it in that javascript/create_task.js?

Answer (score 0):

not sure but, you have...

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    p = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    post_task = PostTaskForm(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    post_task = PostTaskForm()
```

^ so from the above it looks like it might not populate the form if you are making the dialog with a javascript GET request (?)